# Printing in Qt on Windows: Dotted lines lead to big files

Tags: windows, qt, printing, pdf-generation

From a Qt application (Qt 4.7.1), I am printing a diagram, as follows:

- A QPrinter is default-constructed: `QPrinter printer;`
- Color-printing is enabled: `printer.setColorMode( QPrinter::Color );`
- Printer can now be selected by the user: `QPrintDialog printDialog( &printer, this );`
- `printer.setFullPage( true );`
- Initialize a painter using the printer: `QPainter painter( &printer );`

Then, a complex diagram is drawn. I could narrow down the problem to one kind of object: dotted lines. They are created as follows:

- A QPen is created.
- Pen width and pen style are set.
- A number of lines (spanning the whole width of the page) are then drawn with this pen.

For solid lines (Qt::SolidLine), everything is fine (< 100 kB PDF size). But for dotted lines (Qt::DotLine), the PDF is 60 MB big when printing to PDFCreator using A0 and 600 dpi. For lower resolutions, the file size becomes lower as well.

UPDATE: I also tried with the driver for a HP plotter, redirected to a file. This file has 130 MB, so the problem is even worse.

On Linux (KDE), PDFs have a decent size of less than 50 kB.

So apparently, the Qt printing code for Windows / the Windows printing system rasters dotted lines (but not solid lines). Any idea what to do about this problem?

Comment: I'd at least try with Qt 4.8.5. It may be that non-solid line styles have to be rasterized by Qt.